# Is there any possible way to modify the database state from within the scope of a CTE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, cte

For example:

```
-- Directly with a DML Statement
WITH CTE_DML AS
(
    UPDATE Table1
    SET Column1 = 'Value1'
    FROM Table1
)

-- Indirectly by executing a procedure
WITH CTE_SP AS
(
    EXEC sp_ProcedureThatModifiesTheDatabaseState
)

-- Some kind of cross applied function
WITH CTE_FN AS
(
    SELECT Table1.Column1
    FROM Table1
    CROSS APPLY fn_FunctionThatModifiesTheDatabaseState(Table1.Column2)
)
```

I know none of these are valid (and frankly objectively stupid - especially the function) but that's kind of my question. I only know a subset which is what's not possible when it comes to modifying the database state within the scope of a CTE. Is there any way to modify the database state, e.g. a table, from within the scope of a CTE?

Comment: Well, any CTE can say `WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.table) DELETE cte;` - maybe you need to further define "modifiable" and what your actual concern is.

Comment: I know can you run DML statements against a CTE, but my question is specifically in the scope within the CTE itself. E.g: `WITH cte AS (UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = 'Value1' FROM Table1)`

Comment: But my question is also more broad than just raw DML statements, for example if you could execute a stored procedure within a CTE, that would also accomplish my end goal. I'm open to any possible way for modifying the database state within the scope of a CTE.

Comment: No. But if you tell us why or give us more details about what you are actually trying to accomplish, instead of telling us how you've already decided it needs to be accomplished, you may get better help.

Comment: Sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/165455) to me.

Comment: @mustaccio What's an X-Y problem?

Question update on it's way...

Comment: The short answer is "No, CTEs do not modify database state" in SQL Server, nor in almost any other SQL DBMS . You can do that in Postgres but the feature is an extension to the SQL standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically, no.

Technically, yes, but you have to try really hard and have really bad security in place. For example (untested, just for the general idea):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.BadIdea()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
  SET @sql = 'osql -S' +@@servername +' -E -q "UPDATE db.dbo.table... ;"';
  EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @sql;
  RETURN 1;
END
GO

;WITH badIdeaCTE AS 
(
  SELECT x = dbo.BadIdea() FROM sys.all_objects
)
SELECT x FROM badIdeaCTE;
```

There are other ways I think involving `OPENQUERY` or `OPENROWSET`. But generally unless you've set the table specifically to take advantage of these hacks, it's not happening.

Comment: These are the type of answers I'm interested in, lol awesome. Can you please post any other possibilities?